# future.cancel(true) wont stop a single thread in ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduledexecutorservice

In some cases a thread wont stop running even if the result of

```
boolean cancel = future.cancel(true);
```

is true.

This keeps only happening, if I add a thread via `scheduleThread()` to an existing instance of the `scheduler`

If I call `schedule()` instead of `scheduleThread()` at which leads to

```
if (scheduler != null) {
        List<Runnable> shutdownNow = scheduler.shutdownNow();
    }
    scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(elasticsearch2AWSs.size());
    elasticsearch2AWSs.entrySet().forEach(entry -> scheduleThread(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
```

which creates a new instance of `scheduler` and calls `scheduleThread()` to create some thread and cancel them afterwards with `future.cancel(true);` everything works fine.

But when I want to add a thread later on I call `scheduleThread()` directly, the thread starts as expected and I can call `future.cancel(true);` to stop it, the result is `true` but the thread keeps on running. My first thought was, that it has something to do with thread pool size, but that doesn't seem to matter in this case.

What I am missing here? Any help is appreciated!

The `ConnectionScheduler` whichs handles the threads.

```
public final class ConnectionScheduler {

    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;
    private ConcurrentMap<String, ScheduledFuture<?>> futures = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public void schedule(Map<String, Elasticsearch2AWS> elasticsearch2AWSs) {

        if (scheduler != null) {
            List<Runnable> shutdownNow = scheduler.shutdownNow();
        }
        scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(elasticsearch2AWSs.size());
//        scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5); // test purposes

        elasticsearch2AWSs.entrySet().forEach(entry -> scheduleThread(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
    }


    public void scheduleThread(String key, Elasticsearch2AWS elasticsearch2AWS) {
        Map<String, String> awsDimension = elasticsearch2AWS.getAws().get("dimension");
        String dimensionValue = awsDimension.get("value");

        long initialDelay = calcInitialDelay(elasticsearch2AWS.getElasticsearch().get("start"));
        int interval = Integer.valueOf(elasticsearch2AWS.getElasticsearch().get("interval"));
        logger.info("service: {} (start in {} sec and repeats every {} sec)", dimensionValue, initialDelay, interval);

        Runnable task = () -> {
            try {
                logger.info("Runnable task service: {} (start in {} sec and repeats every {} sec)", dimensionValue, initialDelay, interval);
                logger.info("Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted(): {}", Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());

                elasticConnector.startConnector(elasticsearch2AWS);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                logger.error("Exception", ex);
            }
        };
        futures.put(key, scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, initialDelay, interval, TimeUnit.SECONDS)); // filePath is our key

        logger.info("futures '{}'", futures);
    }


    public void stopThread(String key) {
        ScheduledFuture<?> future = futures.remove(key); // remove from our map
        logger.info("stopping task '{}' {}", key, future);
        boolean cancel = future.cancel(true); // cancel the thread
        logger.info("cancel {}", cancel);
        logger.info("futures '{}'", futures);
    }
}
```

The method `watchFolder()` checks for a modified file during runtime. If a file has been modified, a new thread is started via `connectionScheduler.scheduleThread(file.toString(), loadFile(file));` **and this thread does not stop if a call cancel** even though the `cancel` result is true.

For existing files inside the watched folder, which are loaded at program startup, threads are created as well. And this threads **can be successfully canceled** and I don't know whats the difference if I create the threads later on during runtime.

```
public class PropertyReader {
    ...
    public void init() {
        readConfigPropertiesFile();
        readElasticsearchFolder();
        if (thread == null || !thread.isAlive()) {watchFolderThread();}
        connectionScheduler.schedule(elasticsearch2AWSs);
    }

    private void watchFolder() {
        try (final WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService()) {
            foldersToWatch.forEach(path -> path.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY));

            while (true) {                
                final WatchKey watchKey = watchService.take();
                for (WatchEvent<?> event : watchKey.pollEvents()) {

                    final Path file = Paths.get(watchKey.watchable() + File.separator + (Path) event.context());

                    if (event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE || event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY) {
                        logger.info("trigger reschedule of task: '{}'", file);
                        elasticsearch2AWSs.put(file.toString(), loadFile(file));
                        connectionScheduler.scheduleThread(file.toString(), loadFile(file));
                        //connectionScheduler.schedule(elasticsearch2AWSs);
                    }
                    if (event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE) {
                        logger.info("remove task: '{}'", file);
                        connectionScheduler.stopThread(file.toString());
                        elasticsearch2AWSs.remove(file.toString());
                        // TODO remove from executer service
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ...
        } 
    }
}
```

Code shortened for better reading purposes

Comment: The calls you are making are probably blocked on IO operations. Interrupting them won't unblock them - you will have to close the connections.

Comment: Hm ok. But I don't why its possible to close them if I start the threads directly after startup. An even if the threads are running without any meaningful action (just an empty statement or a log entry for example) its not possible to close them